# Timing Animations with Custom Painter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, custom-painter, flutter-custompainter

I created a custom widget in flutter using custom painter. Its a status bar. I wanted to animate it, but now a problem is occurring that I don't know how to fix.

The bar consists of a line and several dots, depending on the status. When animating this bar, the line is correctly animated, but the dot is appearing to early, it just pops in.

[example of how my widget is currently animating (can't post inline yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCWR6.gif)

**How can I choose when the dot animates?**

This is the code I use for animating my widget:

```
class _StatusBarState extends State<StatusBar> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        lowerBound: 1,
        upperBound: widget.states.length.toDouble());
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant StatusBar oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _animationController.animateTo(widget.currentState.toDouble());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _animationController,
          builder: (BuildContext buildContext, Widget? child) => Container(
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: _RentalStatusBarPainter(
                  context: context,
                  currentState: _animationController.value,
                  states: widget.states,
                  failed: widget.error),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: widget.states
                .map((e) => widget.states.indexOf(e) == widget.currentState - 1
                    ? Text(
                        e,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                      )
                    : Text(
                        e,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the custom widget that is being painted:

```
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    int currentStateInt = currentState.toInt();
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Theme.of(context).cardColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    final dotspaint = Paint()
      ..color = Theme.of(context).cardColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final filledpaint = Paint()
      ..color = failed
          ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error
          : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    final filleddotspaint = Paint()
      ..color = failed
          ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error
          : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    //draw the background
    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(0, size.height / 2),
      Offset(size.width, size.height / 2),
      paint,
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStates; i++) {
      final double x = size.width * i / (numberOfStates - 1);

      canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, size.height / 2), 10, dotspaint);
    }

    //draw the filled out stuff
    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(0, size.height / 2),
      Offset(size.width * (currentState - 1) / (numberOfStates - 1),
          size.height / 2),
      filledpaint,
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < currentState; i++) {
      final double x = size.width * i / (numberOfStates - 1);

      canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, size.height / 2), 10, filleddotspaint);
    }
  }
```

Any ideas or insights into how this "automatic" animation actually works is deeply appreciated!

Anton

Comment: check `CustomPainter` constructor - it contains `repaint` parameter - here you can use `AnimationController` for example

Comment: And how could I then trigger the animations independently?

Comment: by calling animation controller's methods, like `forward` / `reverse` etc

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a workaround for this, and have an assumption of why my circles were not animated:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentState - 1; i++) {
    final double x = size.width * i / (numberOfStates - 1);

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, size.height / 2), 10, filleddotspaint);
}

final double x = size.width * (currentState - 1) / (numberOfStates - 1);

canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, size.height / 2), 10, filleddotspaint);
```

I changed the last circle to be drawn **outside** of the for loop. This seems to be enough for the framework to detect that this is something that it should animate. Maybe the for loop confused it in some way?